# How to use mustache tag in json file and get value from Vue?

Tags: json, vue.js, internationalization, mustache, vue-i18n

I am trying vue-i18n and have keep the translation in files according to language.

en.json

```
{
    "Msg1": "You have ",
    "Msg2": " results."
}
```

showResult.vue

```
{{ $t('Msg1')}} {{totalResults}} {{ $t('Msg2')}}
```

Which is able to show the sample output, but let's said if I want to combine all together in single line at en.json, eg:

```
{
    "Msg1": "You have {{totalResults}} results."
}
```

And for showResult.vue I have changed to, which I am not sure is it a correct way:

```
{{Msg1}}
```

And below is the sample output I hope to get:

```
You have 10 results.
```

The **10** is value from **{{totalResults}}**, which will change accordingly.
How can I do so?

Thank you.

Comment: you can try template literals like this ``Msg1: You have ${totalResults} results.``

Comment: I cant put backtick. But cover the statement with the `totalResults` with backticks (*`*)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your replies. I have tried both but failed, the output will be something like: ```You have ${pageStart} results.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ $t('Msg1', { totalResults: 10 }) }
```

> https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/formatting.html#named-formatting

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The ```{{totalResults}}``` is supposed to change accordingly so I can't set a value for it.

Comment: single `{}` `You have {totalResults} results."` @Qness